# Is token normalization implemented in Stanford NLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to normalize tokens (potentially merging them if needed) before running the RegexNER annotator over them.

Is there something already implemented for this in Stanford CoreNLP or in Stanford NLP in general?

If not, what's the best way to implement it? Writing a custom annotator in CoreNLP?

Comment: Could you provide more details about what kind of normalization you are looking for?  There definitely is an annotator for lemmatization.  Also QuantifiableEntityNormalizer can run after NER and normalize numeric quantities like dates, money values, times, percents...What other situations did you have in mind?

Comment: Apologies if I have not made it clear what I was trying to do. I need to convert terms to normative forms, e.g. "earnings" to "net income", "EPS" to "earnings per share", etc. In other words, introduce and execute normalization of lexicon. Lemma and Tokenizer annotators seem to be too low-level for this.

Comment: Ok I think this is going to require a custom annotator.  I'm swamped at the moment, but I can later try to write up some code to guide you in that direction!

Comment: That would be very good. Thank you!

Comment: Please upvote the question if you think it's a good one :)
Thank you!

Comment: I think something like NormalizedTextAnnotation to go along with TextAnnotation is what would be called for at the Token level, if something like that existed.  Whereas TextAnnoation is governed by the start and the end offset, the NormalizedTextAnnotation would be a generic version of the text not limited by the length of the span of that token (as "net income" above is the generic term for "earnings")

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely some options for token normalization.  You apply the -options flag with a comma separated list containing the options you want.

This is described in more detail on this link:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml

Near the bottom there is a section about Options which shows a list of possibilities.

Are there other normalizations you are interested in that are not on that list?